# Google Analytics / Prevent Real Time Data from Expiring on Inactivity

Tags: angular, typescript, google-analytics

I've put Google Analytics on my Angular website in order to view statistics about my website. However, due to my website being one where not much activity occurs (it's a video website where you watch highlights) users can go 20 - 30+ minutes between interactions. Due to how Google Analytics works, it considers the user inactive and removes them from the statistics of the real time count.

Is there anyway to prevent them from expiring, regardless of their inactivity or not? I tried to send a fake event to Google Analytics via my main Angular component but that didn't seem to do anything.

Any help would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ where author can get help with advanced configuration of Google Analytics.

Comment: You can adjust the session duration in the property settings (I think to max four hours) - this is the use case Google had in mind when they introduced that feature.

Comment: Sending an event should also keep the session alive assuming the event is not a non-interaction event.